# How can I create a table from another table without inserting rows (Only want columns) ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I'm trying to create a table from another table (`CREATE TABLE...AS...` statement), but I don't want to insert the rows from the first table. I only need the columns. How?

```
CREATE TABLE employees24
AS (
    SELECT employee_id AS "ID",
      first_name,
      last_name,
      salary,
      department_id AS "DEPT_ID"
    FROM employees);
```

Comment: You can remove the brackets

Answer (score 2):

Something like `create table employees24 as (select * from employees where 0 = 1);` should work.

Comment: thanks alot. i was wondering around and finally found the desired solution to the problem

Answer (score 1):

To create an empty table you just need to pass a select, that will not return any rows:

```
CREATE TABLE employees24
AS (
    SELECT employee_id AS "ID",
      first_name,
      last_name,
      salary,
      department_id AS "DEPT_ID"
    FROM employees
    WHERE 1=2);
```